# What is the physical meaning of the Kondo Temperature?

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, strong-correlated

From my understanding, in a Kondo lattice, the Kondo temperature is where the resistivity dramatically drops. I've also read that the Kondo temperature is the only real "scale" in the physics, with the resisitivity and scattering dependent on the Kondo temperature. My question is, what is the physical meaning of the Kondo temperature, and how does it relate to the coupling strength or interaction strength of the Kondo lattice material?

Answer (score 2):

From what I recall, the Kondo temperature is simply the energy scale associated with the gap formation due to the bound singlet state between the conduction and impurity electron.

In other words I believe $T_K \sim \Delta _K/k_B$, where $\Delta_K$ is the Kondo gap.

The renormalization group analysis of the Kondo impurity problem relates the Kondo temperature to the bandwidth $D$, antiferromagnet coupling $J$, and density of states $\rho$:

$$k_B T_K=D e^{-\frac{1}{J\rho}}$$

[image]